# Hello people, I get an segmentation fault on the program below and I can't figure it out

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int p=2; //nr de thread-uri
int **a, **c;
int n=4;
void *Matrix_Add(void *);


int main(){

int i, j, q;
int *params;                                
pthread_t *ids;                             

a=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);            
c=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
      a[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
      c[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
params=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*p);             
ids=(pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*p);    

  for(i=0; i<n; i++){                       
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        a[i][j]=1;
        }
        }
  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }

  for(q=0; q<p; q++){
    params[q]=q;
    pthread_create(&ids[q], 0, Matrix_Add, (void*)params[q]);
}
for(q=0; q<p; q++){
    pthread_join(ids[q], 0);
}




return 0;


}

void *Matrix_Add(void *params){

int i, j, first, last;
int q=*(int*)params;
int s=n/p;
first=q*s;
last=first+s;

for(i=first; i<last; i++){
    c[i]=0;
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        c[i]+=a[i][j];
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

The program should create 2 threads, divide the 2d array's rows 2 by 2 (2 rows for each thread), and calculate the sum of each row of matrix a and write it in matrix c. Matrix c should have n lines and 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

Change `(void*)params[q]` on the pthread_create line to `(void*)&params[q]`. Matrix_Add expects its params argument to be an int*, not an int.

Comment: After 5k rep, you should know not to answer these types of questions.

Comment: Meh. It'll get closed and I'll have helped someone. I can live with that.

Comment: Yes, i managed to figure it out but now i have another problem. The sum seems to be 16 for every line and i don't understand why. Thank you for your help!